# Complete the information of a table using php to achieve a specific number

Tags: php, html-table, echo

I am designing a calendar using `PHP`, and I want to fill in the lines until I get to number 31. But this does not happen by changing the condition. How can I do this?

```
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <?php

            $day=array("sat","sun","mon","tue","wed","thu","fri");

            echo('<th>'.$day[0].'</th>');
            echo('<th>'.$day[1].'</th>');
            echo('<th>'.$day[2].'</th>');
            echo('<th>'.$day[3].'</th>');
            echo('<th>'.$day[4].'</th>');
            echo('<th>'.$day[5].'</th>');
            echo('<th>'.$day[6].'</th>');

            for($i=1;$i<=31;$i){
            echo("<tr>");
                echo('<td>'.$i++.'</td>');
                echo('<td>'.$i++.'</td>');
                echo('<td>'.$i++.'</td>');
                echo('<td>'.$i++.'</td>');
                echo('<td>'.$i++.'</td>');
                echo('<td>'.$i++.'</td>');
                echo('<td>'.$i++.'</td>');
            echo("</tr>");

        }

        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

[image]

Comment: What about months that don't start on Sunday?

Comment: I know, it's a sample.

Comment: The core issue here is that the the counter is evaluated only when a new iteration is supposed to start. At the start of the final row iteration, `$i` is 29 and then you increment it 7 more times within that single iteration. That's why one would normally specify their counter modification in the `for` loop definition (where you leave it just the same).

Comment: @El_Vanja do you mean using an `if`? Could you please, give me an example?

Comment: Change `for($i=1;$i<=31;$i)` to `for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)`, that would be the usual way. Use this loop to build a multidimensional array to hold the values to be printed. Each subarray would represent one row and hold 7 elements. Once you run out of numbers, you can fill the remaining values with an empty string. When this data is ready, you can output it through a simple `foreach` that would require no additional logic.

Answer (score 0):

In each cell you need to check if it's above 31.

```
            for($i=1;$i<=31;$i){
            echo("<tr>");
                echo('<td>'.($i <= 31 ? $i++ : '').'</td>');
                echo('<td>'.($i <= 31 ? $i++ : '').'</td>');
                echo('<td>'.($i <= 31 ? $i++ : '').'</td>');
                echo('<td>'.($i <= 31 ? $i++ : '').'</td>');
                echo('<td>'.($i <= 31 ? $i++ : '').'</td>');
                echo('<td>'.($i <= 31 ? $i++ : '').'</td>');
                echo('<td>'.($i <= 31 ? $i++ : '').'</td>');
            echo("</tr>");
```